# Typescript Record-like type with single key

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

I was wondering if there is a way to create a version of typescript `Record<K, V>` type where we can enforce only a single field is present. The field key is not known at compile time and can be anything (any random string in the example), but we can't have more than one.

```js
type SingleFieldRecord<K, V> = any; // TODO

let test: SingleFieldRecord<string, number>;

test = { 'some.field': 1 }; // OK
test = { 'another.random.field': 1, 'extra.field': 2 }; // ERROR (too many fields)
```

For my use case I have an object structure representing operators, like so (simplified):

```
type Operator =
  | {
      // $stringIn: SingleFieldRecord<string, string[]>;
      $stringIn: {
        [key: string]: string[];
      };
    }
  | {
      // $numericGE: SingleFieldRecord<string, number>;
      $numericGE: {
        [key: string]: number;
      };
    };
  // ...

// e.g
const op: Operator = {
  $numericGE: {
    'customer.age': 18,
    // I'd like to prevent extra fields here since this api only
    // expects one single field per operator. e.g.

    'customer.height': 6 // this shouldn't be allowed 
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61120160/3106575

Comment: @Shai Thanks. I don't think that solution works for my use case though. As stated, I don't know the property key at compile time. I tried `SingleProperty<Record<string, number[]>>` but that doesn't work.

Comment: Can't you use the `asSinglePropertyObject()` approach as laid out in the other question?  It looks like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJ7z6w).  In any case this is a duplicate of that one

Comment: @jcalz Unfortunately I can't. Thank you though.